# Keras - mismatched array shape with model.predict()

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a simple dense NN with 2 input values written in Keras, running on top of Tensorflow and Python. I have successfully fitted this net and I can run evaluation without errors. However, when I want to predict the result of a single sample data, I get an error due to the dimensions of the input data being incorrectly shaped. However, when I print the shape of the numpy array, it returns the proper shape:

```
inputArr = np.array((x[sample][0], x[sample][1]))
print(inputArr)
print(inputArr.shape)
prediction = model.predict(inputArr)
```

This produces the following output:

```
Input data: [-1. -1.]
Array shape: (2,)
```

Followed by an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\train3d.py", line 60, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict(inputArr)
  File "C:\Users\svoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1147, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "C:\Users\svoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 749, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\svoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 137, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

As you can see from the error message, the net expected an array with dimensions (2, ), which is exactly the same as the output of my input array.

My question is, what exactly is wrong with the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the **batch size**, Keras expects the data to be implicitly `(N, D)` where N is the batch size and D is the number of features. In your case `D=2` but you don't have a matrix.

To pass a single data point you need shape `(1, 2)`, which reads 1 data point with 2 features. You can achieve this by:

```
inputArr = np.array((x[sample][0], x[sample][1]))
print(inputArr) # [-1, -1]
print(inputArr.shape) # (2,)
inputArr = np.expand_dims(inputArr, 0)
print(inputArr.shape) # (1, 2)
```

Or a shorter syntactic sugar version:

```
inputArr = inputArr[None, :] # (1, 2)
```

where `None` adds a new dimension.